# How should one organize a Physics paper focused on an iterative design project?

Tags: publications

If I am writing a paper on a design project rather than to measure something or to test a hypothesis, how should I arrange it?
I have seen that the preferred format is {Introduction, Theory, Methods, Results, Discussion, Citations}. Is it better to attempt to follow this format and remain in the convention, or is this just one of many academically acceptable styles?
How best can I present an iterative design process in a formal physics paper?

Comment: Apply the design to an actual experiment, then write about that